# web services response is not return from my server

Tags: java, php, android, apache, httpclient

I am developing Android apps and for testing purpose i test on localhost  it's runs perfectly but when i host that web service to server at that time no response return from that url.

=> i tried other url like..

https://www.whizapi.com/api/v2/util/ui/in/indian-city-by-postal-code?AppKey=your-app-key&pin=110001

and get response properly as give below.

```
{"ResponseCode":2,"ResponseMessage":"Invalid App Key","ResponseDateTime":"1/6/2015 4:50:28 AM GMT","Data":[]}
```

but from  my server url nothing returns and app display continue loading data .
here is my **doInBackgound(**) method

```
 protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        try {



             try{
        // url where the data will be posted
        //String postReceiverUrl = "http://yoursmarthost.net/~html/androidtest/android_test.php";
        String postReceiverUrl="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&key=API_KEY";
       // String postReceiverUrl="https://www.whizapi.com/api/v2/util/ui/in/indian-city-by-postal-code?AppKey=your-app-key&pin=110001";

        //String postReceiverUrl="http://'my  url'/android_test.php";
        Log.v(TAG, "postURL: " + postReceiverUrl);

        // HttpClient
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        // post header
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(postReceiverUrl);

        // add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("firstname", "Mike"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lastname", "Dalisay"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", "mike@testmail.com"));

        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // execute HTTP post request
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

        if (resEntity!=null) {

            String responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity).trim();
            Log.v(TAG, "Response: " +  responseStr);


        }

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

when i change url and put my web server live url, at that time

```
if (resEntity!=null) {

            String responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity).trim();
            Log.v(TAG, "Response: " +  responseStr);

        }
```

here
debug pointer enter in **EntityUtils.toString(resEntity).trim()**  method but not return back  And continues loading displaying on android app screen.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.whizapi.com/api/v2/util/ui/in/indian-city-by-postal-code?AppKey=**your-app-key**&pin=110001

In this url you have to actually write your app key.

You can get your app key by login into whizapi.com and then go to

https://www.whizapi.com/my-account

You can login into whizapi.com by clicking **Access WhizApi** button on the top right corner on the website.